# Find a function between two arrays that minimises distance between pairs

Tags: r, algorithm, distance

I will explain my problem in general setting (as I am interested in a general algorithm), then decline it to my particular case.

Say we have two finite sets, A and B, both subsets of X and a distance function d that assigns a distance between any two points of X.
What is an algorithm to find two functions: f1 from A to B and f2 from B to A such that f1(a) is the element in B that is closest to a and the same viceversa for f2.

My special case is in R language, where I have two sets of points on earth (lat, lon) and I need to pair them up (from A to B and viceversa) according to their distance.
For reference, I am using the Haversine distance from geosphere package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand if the algorithm is applicable to my case. To avoid confusion I make an example. Say A={5, 3, 12} and B={2, 7, 18, 9}, then the output (from A to B i.e. f1) should be the set {7, 2, 9}.

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioning, this is an algorithmic solution for an algorithmic problem.

Lets begin with a solution in `O(n^2)` time and memory complexity. For each element in `A` remember the distance from each element in `B`. Then iterate over this 2 dimensional array and for each row find its minimum - these elements are the image of `f1`, `f2` is always the reverse function from `f1`.

Now we can create a similar solution in `O(n log n)` time complexity and `O(n)` memory complexity. Using a binary search.

Let's sort the elements in `A` in a way we can say what is the closest item to some item out of the set in `O(log n)`. With numbers it can be done just by sorting them, with `lon & lat` you just need to sort them first by `lon` than by `lat`.

Now for each element in `A` search what is the closest item in `B` using binary search. It will take `O(log n)` per question. Now for each element we know which is the closest. `O(n log n)`.